# Streaming CPU and Ram or sensor data usage from android studio to PowerBI streaming data set ( through REST- end point )

Tags: android, rest, powerbi

I Have successfully implemented a realtime powerbi dashboard ( to monitor CPU and Ram usage ) through Rest API i have used the following powershell script to read values and sent these values via 3 variables Time , Ram and CPU through powershell code to a PowerBi provided end point , as follows ( the end point )

https://api.powerbi.com/beta/xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/datasets/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/rows?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%xxxxxxx%xxxxx%xxxx%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D%3D

Seeking help want to send these variables through an android app the variables will remain same ( Time , CPU and RAm usage ) but this time it will be from android app  ( app is already working fine and capturing the ram and CPU info through Java ,

i have tried Retrofit , Volley example codes but still not able to figure out that how i can send these 3 variables to following power BI streaming data sets end point ?  I am new to REST so seeking help to send ( post these 3 variables in Json format to following power BI end point API as shown in the following powershell code.

I have also tried following HTTP based code but not able to figure out if i can put the following power BI push URL in the following code new HttpPost("http://yoururl"); replaced with power BI URL ?

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("CPU", "15%");   
json.put("RAM", "4 GB");  

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

try {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://yoururl");
    StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    httpClient.execute(request);
// handle response here...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.close();
}
```

All i have got from power BI is following push URL

```
while($true)
{

$ComputerCPU = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_processor -ErrorAction Stop | Measure-Object -Property LoadPercentage -Average | Select-Object Average).Average

$ComputerMemory = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_operatingsystem -ErrorAction Stop
$UsedMemory = $ComputerMemory.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $ComputerMemory.FreePhysicalMemory
$Memory = (($UsedMemory/ $ComputerMemory.TotalVisibleMemorySize)*100)
$RoundMemory = [math]::Round($Memory, 2)
$Date = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy

$Time123 = Get-Date -DisplayHint Time -Format HH:MM:ss
#$Date
#$Time123
#$ComputerCPU
#$RoundMemory

$endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/xxxxxxxxxxx/datasets/xxxxxxxx/rows?key=xxx%xxxxxx%xxxxxxx%xxxxxx%xxxxxxxx%3D%3D"

$payload = @{
"Date" =$Date
"Time" =$Time123
"CPU" = $ComputerCPU
"MEM" = $RoundMemory
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
Write-Host "date: " $Date " time: " $Time123 " cpu: " $ComputerCPU " mem: " $RoundMemory

sleep 0.5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the way
its through using the OkHTTP.